# Create pie chart from html table with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I am trying to create a pie chart from a html table with Highcharts. I had a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic) example to build my code.

**My Code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  data: {
    table: document.getElementById('datatable')
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false
  },
  legend: {
    //align: 'center',
    //verticalAlign: 'top'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Subject Breakdown'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>',
    percentageDecimals: 1
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        color: '#000000',
        connectorColor: '#000000',
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
        },
        
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  }
});
```

**Table & Div:**

```
<div id="container">

<table id='datatable' style='border: 1px solid black'><thead><tr>
<th>Country </th>
<th>Counter</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>
<?php

foreach($analysis_data as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach(['country','counter'] as $attribute){
        echo "<td>".$row[$attribute]."</td>";    // close `td` here
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody></table>
```

The error Message I get is `Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13:` and it refers to [this](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13/) page. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Please take a look at this demo: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module#loading-data-from-a-table and the error which occurs in your project says that the `div` where the chart will be created is missed.

Comment: Thanks. Something was wrong with the div, now I fixed it.